# Prevent InvalidArgumentException on dynamic form field creation

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm following [Symfony cookbook](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms) on dynamic form fields creation.

Basically, in my case, I have a `Product`, a `ProductVersion` and a `Quantity` field in my form.
On new forms, `ProductVersion` is hidden (only with a class attribute, It's still an `EntityType`).

On `Product` change (via select menu), I make an AJAX request to see if some `ProductVersion` exists for this product. If so, I populate the `ProductVersion` with available versions and show it to the user.

It's working fine with new forms. But when editing the same form, I have an `InvalidArgumentException` response on my AJAX request that tells me that the `Quantity` field is `null` :

> Expected argument of type "int", "null" given at property path
> "quantity".

I understand that indeed, I don't provide the `quantity` on my form submission through the AJAX request but that's the purpose of this method isn't it ? To only submit the field that makes a dynamic field change.

How can I do to avoid this Exception ?

Here is the `ItemType` :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('product', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => 'item.product',
            'class' => Product::class,
            'placeholder' => 'item.product',
        ]);

    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Product $product = null) {
        if (null !== $product) {
            $productVersions = $product->getVersions();
            if (count($productVersions) > 0) {
                $form->add('productVersion', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => 'App\Entity\ProductVersion',
                    'placeholder' => 'item.product_version',
                    'choices' => $productVersions,
                    'label' => 'item.product_version'
                ]);
            } else {
                $form->add('productVersion', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => 'App\Entity\ProductVersion',
                    'placeholder' => 'item.product_version',
                    'choices' => [],
                    'label' => 'item.product_version',
                    'disabled' => true,
                    'row_attr' => [
                        //'class' => 'd-none'
                    ]
                ]);
            }
        } else {
            $form->add('productVersion', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'App\Entity\ProductVersion',
                'placeholder' => 'item.product_version',
                'choices' => [],
                'label' => 'item.product_version',
                'disabled' => true,
                'row_attr' => [
                    //'class' => 'd-none'
                ]
            ]);
        }
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();
            $options = $event->getForm()->getConfig()->getOptions();

            //add custom product version according product selected
            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getProduct());

            $form
                ->add('quantity', IntegerType::class, [
                    'label' => 'item.quantity',

                ]);
            if ($data->getId()) {
                $form
                    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                        'label' => $options['submit_btn_label'],
                    ]);
            } else {
                $form
                    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                        'label' => $options['submit_btn_label'],
                    ]);
            }
        }
    );

    $builder->get('product')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
            // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
            $product = $event->getForm()->getData();
            // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
            // the parent to the callback functions!
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $product);
        }
    );
}
```

And here is the Javascript part :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $product = $('#item_product');
  // When product gets selected ...
  $product.on('change', function () {
    console.log("product has changed")
    // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    // Simulate form data, but only include the selected product value.
    var data = {};
    data[$product.attr('name')] = $product.val();

    // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
      url: $form.attr('action'),
      type: $form.attr('method'),
      data: data,
      success: function (html) {
        // Replace current position field ...
        $('#item_productVersion').closest('.form-group').replaceWith(
          // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
          $(html).find('#item_productVersion').closest('.form-group')
        );
        // Position field now displays the appropriate positions.
      }
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: I believe you have the wrong assumption. This error *usually* occurs, when the "starting object", provided to the form when `$this->createForm(YourFormType::class, $object)` in the controller is called, doesn't provide a proper value, which should be an int, which `null` is not. maybe set a default value on your entity's quantity property (like zero). or `'required' => false` (form field option) *might* fix the issue, but I'm not quite certain.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jakumi suggested, adding an `empty_data` option to the `quantity` field solved the problem. Nevertheless, It gives an error on the `quantity` on the form received via the AJAX request and that's normal.

I found that this is not a "clean" method (you have to tweak form fields, you load the entire page on each AJAX request, etc..) so I decided to create a special route dedicated to form submissions that are meant to add/remove/edit fields.

This route creates a **new** form with preset fields (in my case the `product` selected by the user).
Then I can populate the other field (in my case the 'ProductVersion') with a regular `PRE_SET_DATA` Form Event.

This way :
 - I don't have to worry about any other required field
 - I can serialize the entire form in my AJAX request (no need to find the field, everything is done in the form builder)
 - The AJAX request only output the form (I guess this improves performance a bit)

The form builder doesn't change (you still need to listen to `PRE_SET_DATA` **and `POST_SUBMIT`**. If you don't listen to the `POST_SUBMIT`, the form will not know about the `choices` you added dynamically and It will give you an error).

Here is the JS part :

```
$product.on('change', function() {
        // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        // serialize the entire form
        var data = $form.serializeArray();

        // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            url : '/project/item/partial-edit', //custom route
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data : data,
            success: function(html) {
                // Replace current position field ...
                $('#item_productVersion').closest('.form-group').replaceWith(
                    // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
                    $(html).find('#item_productVersion').closest('.form-group')
                );
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the special route :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/item/partial-edit", name="edit_item_partial", requirements={"project"="\d+","item"="\d+"})
     */
    public function edit_item_partial(Request $request)
    {

        $item = new Item();
        $formOption = $request->get('option') ?? array(
            'submit_btn_label' => 'update'
        );
        $form = $this->createForm(ItemType::class, $item, $formOption);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted()){
            //if form was submitted, create a new form with the $item that has now a Product given
            $newForm = $this->createForm(ItemType::class, $item, $formOption);

            //here is the custom view only rendering the form
            return $this->render('item/new_form-only.html.twig', [ 
                'form' => $newForm->createView(),
            ]);

        }
        else {
            return new Response('No form was submitted');
        }

    }
```